# Appendchild to a specific id

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to HTML and CSS and I hope to get some help here :D.
I want to create an `<a>` element at a certain div container with the id navigationPaths, which would be this div container.

```html
<div id="navigationPaths">
```

This is the part of my javascript code which I want to append to this ID. This is what i already found.

```js
var a = document.createElement('a');
var linkText = document.createTextNode("Path");
a.appendChild(linkText);
a.title = "Path";
a.href = "http://google.com";
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

The functions I found doesn't really suit my problem so I hope that someone here knows how this works.

Comment: It's as simple as `document.getElementById("navigationPaths").appendChild(a)` (instead of `document.body`)

Comment: @Phil Yeah thats pretty simple. Thank you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a postscript to Phil's comment, if you didn't want to faff around creating DOM elements, you could create some fully-formed HTML by [inserting an HTML string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) into [the element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

```js
const anchor = '<a title="path" href="http://google.com">Path</a>';
const el = document.querySelector('#navigationPaths');
el.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', anchor);
```

```html
<div id="navigationPaths">New anchor: </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just replace `document.body.appendChild(a)` with `document.getElementById('navigationPaths').appendChild(a)`

Answer (score 1):

to get a specified element in javascript you can use `document.getElementById('navigationPaths')` or `document.queryselector('#navigationPaths')`

then you can save it in a variable then you can append it as a child to it like this

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
var linkText = document.createTextNode("Path");
a.appendChild(linkText);
a.title = "Path";
a.href = "http://google.com";
const navigation = document.getElementById('navigation');
navigation.appendChild(a);
```

`<div id="navigation"></div>`